# Adding link to Jquery EasyUI Tree (with json data)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-easyui

Yes the title says it all..

How to add a link into a Tree that based on json data generated by Jquery EasyUI ?

I've been searching anywhere but got nothing. Already tried to add

```
"attributes":{
    "url":"http://google.com"
}
```

and still not working..

For sure...

HTML

```
<ul class="easyui-tree" data-options="url:'<?php echo Router::url('/files/admin_menu.json'); ?>',method:'get',animate:true,dnd:true,lines:true"></ul>
```

JSON That populated the tree (i want the dashboard menu linked to google.com *for example, but how?)

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "text":"BAMS",
    "children":[{
        "id":13,
        "text":"Dashboard", 
        "iconCls":"icon-home"

    },{
        "id":11,
        "text":"Master",
        "state":"open",
        "children":[{
            "id":111,
            "text":"Brand",
            "iconCls":"icon-brand"
        },{
            "id":112,
            "text":"Vendor",
            "iconCls":"icon-vendor"
        },{
            "id":113,
            "text":"Crew Function Type",
            "iconCls":"icon-user"
        },{
            "id":114,
            "text":"Crew Function",
            "iconCls":"icon-user"
        },{
            "id":115,
            "text":"Crew Position",
            "iconCls":"icon-user"
        },{
            "id":116,
            "text":"Program Type",
            "iconCls":"icon-program"
        }]
    }
}]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: solved with adding url link in JSON data..
"text":"<a href="Ohmygod">Whyitssodifficult</a>",

Answer (score 2):

good one.

In my case, the a hraf= requires single quotes:

```
"text":"<a href='Ohmygod'>Whyitssodifficult</a>"
```

Comment: My guess is that aswzen used backslashes like this: `\"Ohmygod\"` to escape the quote marks. Unfortunately, he forgot to format his comment correctly with backticks, whereupon his backslashes disappeared. His intended solution was most likely `"text":"<a href=\"Ohmygod\">Whyitssodifficult</a>"`.